# C++ copy constructor multiversioning

Tags: c++, templates, memory, vectorization

I wrote a matrix template class. In my copy constructor, I do

```
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T> &M) 
  : _rows(M._rows), _cols(M._cols)
{
    allocate();    // private function for allocating memory
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i)  // size() is a inline function 
                                         // computing the size of the array
        mtx[i] = M.mtx[i];    // mtx is the private member array 
                              // storing the matrix
}
```

For the record, I store my matrix in a 1-D array.

Anyway, when I turn on vectorization in Intel compiler, the vec-report says something like:

> ***non-vectorizable loop instance from multiversioning***

I looked up online, basically it says that the memory is possibly overlapping (link: [Diagnostic 15304: loop was not vectorized: non-vectorizable loop instance from multiversioning](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cdiag15304)).  It suggests that use `__restrict__` to fix it. However, I don't see a way to apply this to a template class and it's members.

Even though this doesn't affect my code, but I am still wondering how can I fix this issue to optimize my code?

Comment: Unrelated: Should your loop not run till `M.size()` instead of `size()`? And how does `allocate()` know how much memory it has to allocate? Can you replace the loop by 1 `memcpy`? That would help the compiler. Something like `memcpy(mtx, M.mtx, sizeof *mtx * size());`.

Comment: @mch I forgot to write the list initializer here. Any way I'll add it here.    And this is an interesting approach. I'll take a look.

Comment: Cannot you mark your `mtx` pointer as restricted? Something as `T* __restrict__ mtx;`?

Comment: @DanielLangr Right, right. I messed up here again. Already correct it.

Comment: @mch Note that `memcpy` will work only for _TriviallyCopyable_ types `T`.

Comment: @DanielLangr Well, I tried to add \__restrict\__, it does not make the compiler complaining, but does not fix this miltiversion issue.

Comment: @SJH What is your compiler and its version? Have you tried adding `#pragma ivdep` before `for` loop?

Comment: @DanielLangr Originally I used Intel-2015.3. And no, I haven't tried `#pragma ivdep`

Comment: @SJH I would suggest first to try a more recent compiler version. If it does not help, you might consider asking in the Intel Developer Forum. You can also play with different compilers and their versions (including Intel) here: https://godbolt.org/z/gt-YGt

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks. I'll try to find if there is any newer version that is available to me.

Comment: It sounds dumb, but maybe the compiler considers the possibility of `&M == this` (in which case memory would overlap)? Not that this should ever happen in reasonable code...

Comment: Like Max Langhof pointed, the compiler wants you to promise `M` and `*this` are different objects. In declaration form, it should look somehwat like this `const Matrix<T> &  __restrict__ M`

Comment: @MaxLanghof I add `__restrict__` at the private part when I declare my pointer, e.g. `T * __restrict__ mtx`. For Intel/2015.3, this doesn't work; after I switch to Intel/2018x, it works.